# How to manipulate dynamic multidimensional-array in C

Tags: c, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I need to alloc a large multidimensional-array as `char a[x][32][y]`, and x*32*y is about 6~12G. (x, y are detenmined at runtime.)

I think out a way that is to do `char *a=malloc(x*32*y)`, and use `*(a+32*y*i+y*j+k)` for  `a[i][j][k]`.

However, this looks not so convient comparing to `a[i][j][k]`.

Is there any better way ?

Added:
It is `a[x][32][datlen]`, where `datlen` is detenmined at runtime and `x` is set considering the memory.

The whole data in the array will be new. And I have got mathines with 16 or 32GB memory to run it.

Comment: Consider a macro or inline function? For such a large data-set, consider using mmap and/or other locality-increasing techniques -- which may not be the same 'flat' array.

Comment: Also what does `a[X][N][Y]` conceptually map to? I'll bet you could leave the data on disk using BDB, Sqlite, or HDF5 and have your program retrieve appropriate sized chunks. As your question stands we are only guessing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INCORRECT: You should still be able to use a[i][j][k] syntax when referencing dynamically allocated memory.

CORRECT: Use a macro to at least make the job easier

```
#define A(i,j,k) *(a+32*y*i+y*j+k)
A(1,2,3) would then do the right thing.
```

Comment: It's not possible because the *size* of the dimensions are not known at compile-time -- and even with run-time support, one can't assign to a variable of type `char[x][32][y]`. (Unless I am just dated to C89, which is a very good possibility.)

Comment: @pst: Hmm.  Good point.  It works with single-dimensional arrays but I didn't think about the restrictions you are working under carefully enough.  I revised the answer to suggest macros.

Comment: Still won't work because macros are fixed definition. You can't change that `32*y` at runtime.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: You **can** compute 32*y at runtime.  A macro just provides textual subtitution of the parameters.  So A(1,2,3) gets translated into *(a+32*y*1+y*2+3) and the system computes that at runtime just as if you wrote that code there.  It should not be confused with compiler constant expression reduction (which might occur on the results of the macro substitution, but would not in this case).

Comment: @Seth: Say you decide the array should be reallocated as 64 instead of 32? Your macro won't work. A data structure and functions that track the current array dimensions is better.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: I am not responsibly for the lack of objectness of the original poster.  If it were me, at a minimum I would make 32 another #defined constant so that it would only have to be changed at one location.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll find a system which will allocate you contiguous memory that large*. You're going to have to utilize a chunking strategy of some kind.

You need to ask, "What is your data access pattern?"

If it is some stride (be it 1D or 2D), use that to choose an appropriate allocation of memory for each chunk. Use a data structure to represent each stride (might just be a struct containing your character arrays).

**Edit:** I didn't notice your second "question" about accessing your newly found 12G contiguous chunk of memory using `a[i][j][k]` syntax. That isn't going to happen in any consumer grade C distribution I'm aware of.

(*) and 640k ought to be enough memory for anyone.

Comment: For example, if you're accessing `X` blocks of `char[32][Y]`, then perform the chunking across `X`.

Comment: Even better, `X` chunks (where X is strictly greater than 32 * Y) is probably a good bet. If and only if you're working on the 32 * Y portion, and not some strange column ordering stride (a la Fortran).

Comment: I wonder why contiguous memory is a problem as long as the free memory + swap space is enough. I remember malloc(and all userspace pointers) will return a virtual address and the Linux kernel will deal with physical mapping.

Comment: `malloc` isn't always able to do so I've found. Usually in those situations I've used `mmap`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is C you cannot wrap everything up into a handy C++ object.

But I would do something similar. Design a series of functions that allocate, manipulate and destroy this new data type of yours.

To read or write a piece of the data, call a function. Never touch the data directly. In fact, if you can use a `void*` handle to your data and not even put the real data types in an included header file, that's the best thing to do.

With this, you can define the functions as operating on one very large memory block, a set of large memory blocks or even an on-disk database of blocks.

Now that I wrote that, let me partly take it back. If you need more performance you might want to define all of the functions in the included header file as inline definitions. That will let your compiler remove almost all the function call overhead and optimize aggressively.

I admit that `matrix_set(x, y, z, value)` is not as pretty as `matrix[x][y][z]  = value`, but it will work just as well.